# I have to get month and year from due_dt column and pass that as input in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select sum(NVL(CL.TOTAL_REPAY_AMT,0) + NVL(re.INSURANCE_DUE_AMT,0)) as installment_amount
       , sum(RE.LI_DUE_AMT) as life_insurance
       , sum(RE.PI_DUE_AMT) as property_insurance
       , (SUM(NVL(CL.TOTAL_REPAY_AMT,0) + NVL(re.INSURANCE_DUE_AMT,0)) + SUM(RE.LI_DUE_AMT) + SUM(RE.PI_DUE_AMT)) as total_amount
       , count(cl.ref_num_1) as Count_loans
       , SUM(cl.DR_INTRST_RT) AS INTREST
from cr_loan cl
join repayment_events re on cl.pos_num = re.pos_num 
and CL.DR_INTRST_RT = 0
and RE.LAST_EVENT_STAT IN (1,11) 
AND RE.DUE_DT = '01-JUNE-2083'
```

I am trying to extract month and year and pass that as input for due_dt column. I tried using substring but that didn't work:

```
SUBSTR(RE.DUE_DT, 4,15) ='JUNE-2083'
```

Please help me

Comment: which rdbms it is ?

Comment: What is the data type of column `DUE_DT`?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is quite unclear what `DUE_DT` looks like.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what is `RE.DUE_DT` column's datatype.

If it is `DATE`, then provide date to it:

```
AND RE.DUE_DT = date '2083-06-01'
```

Regarding what you wrote ("I am trying to extract month and year and pass that as input for due_dt column"), that might be

```
AND RE.DUE_DT >= date '2083-06-01' 
AND RE.DUE_DT <  date '2083-07-01'
```

If it is `VARCHAR2`, what does it contain? If it is something like `'06.2083'`. In that case, you'd simply provide matching string to it:

```
AND RE.DUE_DT = '06.2083'
```

Basically, the whole problem goes back to the first sentence I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using ORACLE. You can write as given below:

```
TO_CHAR(RE.DUE_DT,'month-YYYY') ='JUNE-2083'
```

[TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm)

Comment: getting all as null values. same thing is happening with SUBSTR function also

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want:

```
where due_dt >= to_date(:year || '-' || :month, 'YYYY-MM') and
      due_dt < add_months(to_date(:year || '-' || :month, 'YYYY-MM'), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use the below

```
replace(to_char(RE.DUE_DT,'MONTH-yyyy'),' ','')='JUNE-2083'
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already asked, please confirm the datatype of DUE_DT column

`select data_type from all_tab_cols where table_name = 'REPAYMENT_EVENTS' and column_name = 'DUE_DT' ;`

Assuming it's `date`:

```
    select sum(NVL(CL.TOTAL_REPAY_AMT,0) + NVL(re.INSURANCE_DUE_AMT,0)) as installment_amount
           , sum(RE.LI_DUE_AMT) as life_insurance
           , sum(RE.PI_DUE_AMT) as property_insurance
           , (SUM(NVL(CL.TOTAL_REPAY_AMT,0) + NVL(re.INSURANCE_DUE_AMT,0)) + SUM(RE.LI_DUE_AMT) + SUM(RE.PI_DUE_AMT)) as total_amount
           , count(cl.ref_num_1) as Count_loans
           , SUM(cl.DR_INTRST_RT) AS INTREST
    from cr_loan cl
    join repayment_events re on cl.pos_num = re.pos_num 
    and CL.DR_INTRST_RT = 0
    and RE.LAST_EVENT_STAT IN (1,11) 
    -- AND RE.DUE_DT = '01-JUNE-2083'
    and TO_CHAR(RE.DUE_DT,'MM-YYYY') = '06-2083'
    ;
```